# Reply Kafka Template - Exception handling

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` to establish a synchronous call between two microservices. 
The receiver of the event is annotated with `SendTo` as below:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.prefix}"
        + "${kafka.topic.name}", containerFactory = "customEventKafkaListenerFactory")
@SendTo
public CustomResponseEvent onMessage(
        @Payload @Valid CustomRequestEvent event, @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) String correlationId,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) String replyTopic) {

   //Making some REST API calls to another external system here using RestTemplate
}
```

The REST API call can throw a 4xx or 5xx. There are multiple such calls, some to internal systems, and some to external systems. It may be a bad design, but let's not get into that.

I would like to have a global exception handler for the `RestTemplate` where I can catch all the exceptions, and then return a response to the original sender of the event.
I am using the same `replyTopic` and `correlationId` as received in the consumer to publish the event. 
But still the receiver of the response throws `No pending reply` exception.

1. Whatever approach I have above, is it possible to achieve such a central error response event publisher?
2. Is there any other alternative that is best suited for this exception handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@KafkaListener` comes with the:

```
/**
 * Set an {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaListenerErrorHandler} bean
 * name to invoke if the listener method throws an exception.
 * @return the error handler.
 * @since 1.3
 */
String errorHandler() default "";
```

That one is used to catch and process all the downstream exceptions and if it returns a result, it is sent back to the `replyTopic`:

```
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    Message<?> message = toMessagingMessage(record, acknowledgment, consumer);
    logger.debug(() -> "Processing [" + message + "]");
    try {
        Object result = invokeHandler(record, acknowledgment, message, consumer);
        if (result != null) {
            handleResult(result, record, message);
        }
    }
    catch (ListenerExecutionFailedException e) { // NOSONAR ex flow control
        if (this.errorHandler != null) {
            try {
                Object result = this.errorHandler.handleError(message, e, consumer);
                if (result != null) {
                    handleResult(result, record, message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException(createMessagingErrorMessage(// NOSONAR stack trace loss
                        "Listener error handler threw an exception for the incoming message",
                        message.getPayload()), ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

See `RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter` source code for more info.